# Unable to assign a nullptr in a forwarding reference after using the object for initializing inside move constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, move

I am trying to get used to the move constructor and in one of tutorials it was told that it is always a good practice to initialize the original refence to the nullptr after copying the content using a forwarding reference.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class Matrix{
  std::vector<std::vector<T>> data;
public :
  Matrix(const std::vector<std::vector<T>>& vector2D){ //Copy constructor for deep copy
    // Put some error handling to check the validity of vector2D

    std::cout<<"Copy Constructor Called ...\n";
    __uint32_t numRow = vector2D.size();
    __uint32_t numColumn = vector2D[0].size();

    data.resize(numRow,std::vector<T>(numColumn));

    for(auto row = 0u;row < numRow; ++row){
        for(auto column = 0u; column < numColumn; ++column){
            data[row][column] = vector2D[row][column];
        }
    }
  } 

  Matrix(std::vector<std::vector<T>>&& vector2D){   //Move constructor for shallow copy
    // Put some error handling to check the validity of vector2D
    std::cout<<"Move Constructor Called ...\n";
    data = vector2D;
    //vector2D = nullptr;    // we should assign the original reference to null in my knowledge
  }

  void displayVector(){
    __uint32_t numRow = data.size();
    __uint32_t numColumn = data[0].size();
    for(auto row = 0u;row < numRow; ++row){
        for(auto column = 0u; column < numColumn; ++column){
            std::cout<<data[row][column]<<"\t";
        }std::cout<<std::endl;
    }
  }

  Matrix operator+ (const Matrix& rhs){
    // Have to complete
    return data;
  }
  Matrix operator* (const Matrix& rhs){
    // Have to complete
    return data;
  }
};

int main() {
  cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!

  //Matrix<int> m1(std::vector<std::vector<int>>{{1,2},{3,4}});
  Matrix<int> m1({{1,2},{3,4}});
  m1.displayVector();

  std::vector<std::vector<int>> myVector{{5,6},{7,8}};
  Matrix<int> m2(myVector);
  m2.displayVector();
  return 0;
}
```

But, when I am attempting to put nullptr inside vector2D inside the move constructor the compiler is complaining saying

no known conversion for argument 1 from std::nullptr_t to std::initializer_list of std::vector.

What are a few possibly correct ways to do such an initialization.

Comment: There is no such thing as a null reference.

Answer (score 2):

Two things here:

```
 Matrix(std::vector<std::vector<T>>&& vector2D){   //Move constructor for shallow copy
// Put some error handling to check the validity of vector2D
std::cout<<"Move Constructor Called ...\n";
data = vector2D;
//vector2D = nullptr;    // we should assign the original reference to null in my knowledge
```

}

1) you should move the received vector, to invoke vectors move assignment operator:

```
data = std::move(vector2D);
```

2) no need to manually set the vector to nullptr, it's state is already properly set.
The vector you move from is left in an "unknown, but valid state", so you can do with it anything that does not assume precondition (reasign, check size, check for emptiness, etc., you can't however expect it to have valid values inside).
As the other answer mentioned, you should also directly initialize the data, instead of doing it in the constructor body, so finally the constructor should be implemented this way probably:

```
 Matrix(std::vector<std::vector<T>>&& vector2D) : data(std::move(vector2D)) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be writing that:

```
// Not a move constructor, that would be `Matrix(Matrix&&)`
Matrix(std::vector<std::vector<T>>&& vector2D) : data(std::move(vector2D)) {
    std::cout<<"Move non-Constructor Called ...\n";
}
```

Vectors cannot be `nullptr`, but they can be empty - `data(std::move(vector2D))` will empty the original vector and move the contents to `data`.